# Writing a main driver with Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to

- create a surface object using whatever parameters
- call the `getRect()` method on the surface object, and save the result rectangle in a variable.

and print the result.

```
    class Rectangle:
        def __init__(self, x, y, h, w):
            self.x = x
           self.y = y
           self.h = h
           self.w = w
       def __str__(self):
           return "(x:)"+str(self.x) + ", y=" + str(self.y) + ", width:" + str(self.w) + ", height:" + str(self.h)
```

and this is Class Surface

```
    from Rectangle import Rectangle

    class Surface:
        def __init__(self, filename, x, y, h, w):
            self.image = filename
            self.rect = Rectangle(x, y, h, w)
        def getRect(self):
            return self.rect
```

This is my main function so far

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle 
from Surface import Surface

def main():

    my_surface = Surface(2,4,2,4)
    my_rectangle = my_surface.getRect()
    print(my_surface.Rectangle)

()
```

To print `__str__` from class Rectangle without calling `__str__`function explicitly, I put `print(my_surface.Rectangle)`, but it does not print anything. What should I write instead of the code?

Comment: what is `my_serface`?

Comment: change  `my_rectangle = getRect(my_surface)` to `my_rectangle = my_surface.getRect()`

Answer (score 2):

Call the function `main()`. `()` by itself doesn't do anything.

You also didn't give the Surface a filename, and there's no such thing as `my_surface.Rectangle`. So the complete code should look like:

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle
from Surface import Surface


def main():
    my_surface = Surface("filename", 2, 4, 2, 4)
    my_rectangle = my_surface.getRect()
    print(my_rectangle)


main()
```